# How to decrypt video file with an video player in js

Tags: javascript, html, video

**I have a encrypted video file using AES.
What I want to do is decrypt this video and show it in the html page.
I have tried this code but I'm getting this erorr** **`b:http://127.0.0.1:5500/aa3733be-071e-4e59-8fd1-f9f268bbc67d net::ERR_REQUEST_RANGE_NOT_SATISFIABLE`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Encrypted Video Player</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.5/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video controls>
      <source src="/vids/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>

    <script>
      // Set your decryption key
      var decryptionKey = "aoXOliDbjtkrfPpOi7J7yg==";
      
      // Load the encrypted video file
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', '/vids/video.mp4', true);
      xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
      xhr.onload = function() {
        // Decrypt the video file
        var decryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(new Uint8Array(this.response), decryptionKey);
        var decryptedBlob = new Blob([decryptedData], {type: 'video/mp4'});
        var decryptedUrl = URL.createObjectURL(decryptedBlob);

        // Set the decrypted video source
        var videoPlayer = document.querySelector('video');
        videoPlayer.src = decryptedUrl;
        videoPlayer.load();
      };
      xhr.send();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: has your request returned the whole video, and has the decryption correctly given you back the mp4?